# How to check if all the four multiselect has some value selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 multiselect which are created dynamically by this fashion

```
var drp_nt = $('<select />', {
                              'id'     : 'drp_' + nt,
                              'name'   : 'drp_' + nt+'[]',
                              'multiple': true});

var drp_cnt = $('<select />', {
                              'id'     : 'drp_' + cnt,
                              'name'   : 'drp_' + cnt+'[]',
                              'multiple': true});

var drp_ctg = $('<select />', {
                              'id'     : 'drp_' + ctg,
                              'name'   : 'drp_' + ctg+'[]',
                              'multiple': true});

var drp_api = $('<select />', {
                              'id'     : 'drp_' + api,
                              'name'   : 'drp_' + api+'[]',
                              'multiple': true});
```

Now I want to make a function called

```
function check_selection()
{
-----------------
-----------------
}
```

which will contain the code to check whether all of the multiselect has any of the data selected.

Also how can I call this function by using and event from all the 4 multiselect dropdowns(since this function will be triggered whenever any option is selected from any of the multiselect)

I tried the onchange event for multiselect, but it didn't call the function.

Answer (score 1):

use `change event` to check all select box is selected or not using **filter()**

```
$("select").change(function () {

    var selectedBox = $("select").filter(function () {
        return this.value != "";
    });
    if (selectedBox.length == 4) {
        alert("4 ckecked")
    }

});
```

For dynamic element

```
$(document).on("change", "select[id^=drp_]", function(){
       var selectedBox = $("select").filter(function () {
            return this.value != "";
        });
        if (selectedBox.length == 4) {
            alert("4 ckecked")
        }

    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dbr8dxmu/11/)**

Comment: @Saswat I think my code is working fine .. what is the issue you have ,can you make sample in fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gwL07wbs/15/             do inspect element to check from console........... then u can see the function in the onchange of the html.... but even if you select any of the options, the alert won't trigger

Comment: @Saswat you have to bind the event initilay that is good idea ..use start with selector like "select[id^=drp_]"